# What is cause of the spike in tx_bad_seq ? Presumably overloaded stellar network

Tags: sequence-number

Starting around Feb 15, started seeing huge spike in tx_bad_seq on my kelp server. I was using the public Horizon. You can see from the lines below the massive increase.

Presumably this is due to the fully ledgers and/or timeouts on response? On a timed out response from Horizon, kelp probably assumes that the sequence number is unchanged, when presumably that's unknown since you never got a response and this is just a bug in kelp to not get the sequence number after a gateway timeout (cloudflare in front of Horizon). It doesn't recognize the > in the cloudflare response... probably should re-load txn number at that point.

Seq number issues can come from a node that's lagging behind, horizon lagging behind core. I was connected to the public horizon server.

Perhaps it was the cloudflare timeout messages.

here are the seq errors:

```
    stk@steve-kelp:~$ sudo journalctl -u kelp-XLM|grep seq
Feb 15 15:35:44 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:35:44 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seq number
Feb 15 15:35:44 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:35:44 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 15 15:37:33 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:37:33 reloading sequence number
Feb 15 15:37:34 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:37:34 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seq number
Feb 15 15:37:34 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:37:34 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 15 15:39:44 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:39:44 reloading sequence number
Feb 15 15:43:44 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:43:44 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seq number
Feb 15 15:43:44 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:43:44 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 15 15:45:45 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:45:45 reloading sequence number
Feb 15 15:47:48 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:47:48 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seq number
Feb 15 15:47:48 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:47:48 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 15 15:49:33 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:49:33 reloading sequence number
Feb 17 10:55:44 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/17 10:55:44 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seq number
Feb 17 10:55:44 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/17 10:55:44 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 17 10:57:34 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/17 10:57:34 reloading sequence number
Feb 17 20:57:47 steve-kelp bash[6493]: 2019/02/17 20:57:47 reloading sequence number
Feb 17 21:11:05 steve-kelp bash[7425]: 2019/02/17 21:11:05 reloading sequence number
Feb 17 21:13:15 steve-kelp bash[7425]: 2019/02/17 21:13:15 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seq number
Feb 17 21:13:15 steve-kelp bash[7425]: 2019/02/17 21:13:15 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 17 21:17:06 steve-kelp bash[7425]: 2019/02/17 21:17:06 reloading sequence number
Feb 17 23:25:33 steve-kelp bash[9742]: 2019/02/17 23:25:33 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 00:19:39 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 00:19:39 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 01:11:51 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:11:51 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 01:11:51 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:11:51 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 01:13:41 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:13:41 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 01:13:41 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:13:41 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 01:13:41 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:13:41 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 01:15:41 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:15:41 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 01:19:51 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:19:51 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 01:19:51 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:19:51 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 01:21:40 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:21:40 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 01:23:50 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:23:50 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 01:23:50 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:23:50 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 01:25:40 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:25:40 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 01:25:41 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:25:41 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 01:25:41 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:25:41 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 01:27:40 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:27:40 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 01:27:40 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:27:40 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 01:27:40 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:27:40 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 01:29:40 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:29:40 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 01:29:40 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:29:40 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 01:29:40 steve-kelp bash[12059]: 2019/02/18 01:29:40 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 01:31:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:31:33 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 01:31:34 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:31:34 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 01:31:34 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:31:34 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 01:33:32 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:33:32 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 01:33:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:33:33 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 01:33:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:33:33 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 01:35:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:35:33 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 01:35:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:35:33 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 01:35:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:35:33 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 01:37:32 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:37:32 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 01:39:43 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:39:43 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 01:39:43 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:39:43 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 01:41:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:41:33 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 01:41:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:41:33 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 01:41:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:41:33 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 01:43:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:43:33 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 01:43:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:43:33 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 01:43:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:43:33 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 01:45:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:45:33 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 01:45:35 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:45:35 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 01:45:35 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:45:35 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 01:47:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:47:33 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 01:47:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:47:33 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 01:47:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:47:33 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 01:49:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:49:33 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 01:51:44 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:51:44 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 01:51:44 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:51:44 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 01:53:33 steve-kelp bash[14744]: 2019/02/18 01:53:33 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 04:00:22 steve-kelp bash[18635]: 2019/02/18 04:00:22 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 04:00:34 steve-kelp bash[18635]: 2019/02/18 04:00:34 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 18 04:00:34 steve-kelp bash[18635]: 2019/02/18 04:00:34 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 18 04:50:46 steve-kelp bash[19791]: 2019/02/18 04:50:46 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 05:02:03 steve-kelp bash[19877]: 2019/02/18 05:02:03 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 19:45:23 steve-kelp bash[26586]: 2019/02/18 19:45:23 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 19:59:44 steve-kelp bash[28144]: 2019/02/18 19:59:44 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 20:10:38 steve-kelp bash[29497]: 2019/02/18 20:10:38 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 20:13:14 steve-kelp bash[29888]: 2019/02/18 20:13:14 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 20:20:38 steve-kelp bash[30772]: 2019/02/18 20:20:38 reloading sequence number
Feb 18 22:52:11 steve-kelp bash[790]: 2019/02/18 22:52:11 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 11:28:38 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:28:38 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 11:28:39 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:28:39 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 11:28:39 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:28:39 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 11:32:00 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:32:00 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 11:32:00 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:32:00 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 11:32:00 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:32:00 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 11:35:45 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:35:45 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 11:35:45 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:35:45 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 11:35:45 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:35:45 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 11:39:24 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:39:24 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 11:39:24 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:39:24 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 11:39:24 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:39:24 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 11:42:36 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:42:36 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 11:45:55 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:45:55 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 11:45:55 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:45:55 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 11:49:01 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:49:01 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 11:56:47 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:56:47 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 11:56:47 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:56:47 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 11:59:43 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 11:59:43 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 12:16:00 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:16:00 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 12:16:00 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:16:00 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 12:19:46 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:19:46 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 12:19:46 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:19:46 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 12:19:46 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:19:46 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 12:23:08 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:23:08 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 12:23:08 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:23:08 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 12:23:08 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:23:08 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 12:29:46 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:29:46 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 12:29:46 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:29:46 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 12:29:46 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:29:46 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 12:36:20 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:36:20 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 12:36:20 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:36:20 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 12:36:20 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:36:20 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 12:40:05 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:40:05 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 12:40:05 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:40:05 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 12:40:05 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:40:05 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 12:47:29 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:47:29 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 12:47:29 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:47:29 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 12:47:29 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:47:29 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 12:51:01 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:51:01 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 12:51:01 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:51:01 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 12:51:01 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:51:01 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 12:54:53 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:54:53 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 12:54:54 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:54:54 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 12:54:54 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:54:54 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 12:58:28 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:58:28 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 12:58:28 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:58:28 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 12:58:28 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 12:58:28 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 13:02:25 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 13:02:25 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 13:06:07 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 13:06:07 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 13:06:07 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 13:06:07 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 13:12:25 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 13:12:25 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 13:12:26 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 13:12:26 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 13:12:26 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 13:12:26 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 13:16:24 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 13:16:24 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 13:20:34 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 13:20:34 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 13:20:34 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 13:20:34 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 13:23:57 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 13:23:57 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 13:27:45 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 13:27:45 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 13:27:45 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 13:27:45 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 13:30:43 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 13:30:43 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 13:30:43 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 13:30:43 (async) error: tx_bad_seq, setting flag to reload seqnumber
Feb 20 13:30:43 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 13:30:43 (async) error: result code details: tx code = tx_bad_seq , opcodes = []
Feb 20 13:34:34 steve-kelp bash[24060]: 2019/02/20 13:34:34 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 22:59:24 steve-kelp bash[2398]: 2019/02/20 22:59:24 reloading sequence number
Feb 20 23:24:48 steve-kelp bash[4127]: 2019/02/20 23:24:48 reloading sequence number
Feb 21 00:06:58 steve-kelp bash[6792]: 2019/02/21 00:06:58 reloading sequence number
Feb 21 01:56:26 steve-kelp bash[13536]: 2019/02/21 01:56:26 reloading sequence number
Feb 21 03:28:52 steve-kelp bash[14682]: 2019/02/21 03:28:52 reloading sequence number
Feb 21 14:58:27 steve-kelp bash[23096]: 2019/02/21 14:58:27 reloading sequence number
stk@steve-kelp:~$

> Blockquote
```

and here are (just a few of) the gateway timeout errors (the < character is from cloudflare telling you it timed out... that < is the start of the HTML from cloudflare)

```
Feb 15 08:16:04 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 08:16:04 (async) error: tx failed for unknown reason, error message: error decoding horizon.Problem: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Feb 15 10:06:04 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 10:06:04 (async) error: tx failed for unknown reason, error message: error decoding horizon.Problem: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Feb 15 12:18:04 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 12:18:04 (async) error: tx failed for unknown reason, error message: error decoding horizon.Problem: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Feb 15 14:00:04 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 14:00:04 (async) error: tx failed for unknown reason, error message: error decoding horizon.Problem: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Feb 15 14:08:03 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 14:08:03 (async) error: tx failed for unknown reason, error message: error decoding horizon.Problem: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Feb 15 15:04:04 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:04:04 (async) error: tx failed for unknown reason, error message: error decoding horizon.Problem: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Feb 15 15:34:08 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:34:08 (async) error: tx failed for unknown reason, error message: error decoding horizon.Problem: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Feb 15 15:40:15 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:40:15 (async) error: tx failed for unknown reason, error message: error decoding horizon.Problem: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Feb 15 15:42:09 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:42:09 (async) error: tx failed for unknown reason, error message: error decoding horizon.Problem: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Feb 15 15:46:16 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:46:16 (async) error: tx failed for unknown reason, error message: error decoding horizon.Problem: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Feb 15 15:50:04 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 15:50:04 (async) error: tx failed for unknown reason, error message: error decoding horizon.Problem: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Feb 15 16:00:56 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 16:00:56 (async) error: tx failed for unknown reason, error message: error decoding horizon.Problem: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Feb 15 16:02:27 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/15 16:02:27 (async) error: tx failed for unknown reason, error message: error decoding horizon.Problem: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Feb 16 07:10:05 steve-kelp bash[6045]: 2019/02/16 07:10:05 (async) error: tx failed for unknown reason, error mess
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the blog post: [Surge pricing on Stellar: FAQ](https://medium.com/stellar-developers-blog/surge-pricing-on-stellar-faq-1cd6e4aa6010)

> Over the past few days, a lot of Stellar users have had trouble
>   submitting transactions due to an increase in network activity.
>   Ledgers that are full to the brim, often with failed transactions,
>   have become increasingly common.
>
> Here’s a snapshot of the last 200 ledgers as of writing these lines,
>   from the Stellar dashboard... about a quarter of the ledgers are maxed
>   out at 50 transactions